# Referencing this in .querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If I use the following to select a certain node

```
var Link = document.querySelector('table .ctrlcLink');
```

I get the first column value for the column with class ctrlLink, which is what I expected.

However, since I have an onclick event set to an other column in the same table, I would like to get the value of the .ctrlLink column that is on the same row as my clicked element.
So I tried something like this:

```
var Link = document.querySelector($(this).closest('tr').children('td.ctrlcLink'));
```

But then I get

> "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object Object]' is
>   not a valid selector."

What selector should I use then?

EDIT:
Maybe I should've added that I need it so that I can use the following afterwards:

```
var range = document.createRange();  
range.selectNode(Link);  
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
```

EDIT2:
as suggested, I created a codepen page for this (thanks for that!).:
http://codepen.io/whatwhat/pen/JXJjOp
The thing I'm trying to get is that when I click the image in the table, I fetch the text on the same row in the cell next to it and put it in my ctrl-c.
However, I am unable to get the exact rownumber of the image I click.
This part doesnt work:

```
var rowIndex = $(this).index();
```

What would work, how could I get the rownumber.?
I would then concatenate it changing

```
var Link = document.querySelector('#docReport tr:nth-child(1) .ctrlcLink');
```

to

```
var Link = document.querySelector('#docReport tr:nth-child('+rowIndex+') .ctrlcLink');
```

Or can I resolve this in another way?

EDIT3:
I eventually got what I needed like this:
http://codepen.io/whatwhat/pen/GZEgKK

Comment: Please post minimalistic sample replicating your issue because actually your question doesn't really makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery Event, instead of 'onclick'.

http://codepen.io/nigayo/pen/oxwYwz?editors=1010

```
$("#docReport img.smiley-img").on("click", function(){

  var Link = $(this).parent().prev()[0];
  var range = document.createRange();
  //blah...blah..
});
```

Comment: In my html I have
    onclick="ctrlc(this);"

In my js:
    function ctrlc(link) {
      var Link = link.target.nextSibling.querySelector('td.ctrlcLink');
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(Link);
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      var successful = document.execCommand('copy');}

Yet i get error mssg "Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined"

Comment: I am new at this, I cant seem to format my comment.

Comment: @user3615590  You should refer to this link.  http://codepen.io/nigayo/pen/wGdQQK

Comment: thanks for the tip, I created a codepen page and edited it in my original post.

Comment: @user3615590 , I wrote well working code on new codepen page.